# Are $scope variables case sensitive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The title says it all really. Would the following statement return true or false?

`$scope.feed === $scope.Feed`

I'm currently converting a web app from AngularJS 1.x into React, and I've stumbled upon a scope variable `feed`, of which's origin I cannot seem to understand. In another file however the scope variable `Feed` is being given a value, so I'm simply wondering if these two reference the same variable. Are Angular $scope variables case sensitive?

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive.

Comment: That is very true, @Legends. I've realised this was a very stupid question indeed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to names of directives, controllers, modules etc then yes. else normally js is case sensitive.